# For loop program returns [value]i instead of [value]

Tags: c, for-loop

I made a simple program but it's printing `"twoi=..."` instead of `"two"`. I tried re-arranging the `for`-loop in the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 2)
        {
            printf("two");
        }
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop does not return anything.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I think OP meant printing instead of returning.

Comment: A correct title would be *"twoi" printed instead of "two"* or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a newline after `"two"`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 2)
        {
            printf("two\n");
        }
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

... or use `puts()` which adds a newline by itself: `puts("two");`

Comment: puts works great! It looks like it can be used in many ways. Thanks fish.


Now I'm wondering what the difference between puts & printf is. Google here I come :P... oh. %d %f